# Android Espresso 2.2.1 Resolved versions for app and test app differ

Tags: android, android-espresso

Running tests via Android Studio, Gradle

Espresso:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
```

Library:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
```

Runner:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':application'.

```
> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app and test app differ.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'` from your `build.gradle`. Take a look on example [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/BasicSample/app/build.gradle).

Answer (score 0):

Get comfortable with command-line Gradle. This tool help you find any conflicting dependencies when you run from console that command `gradle -q app:dependencies`.

Instead of deleting `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'` from your app's `build.gradle` file, you can add `exclude` part like here.

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
                   exclude module: 'support-annotations'
```

}

Hope it help.